# Number of threads that can be created in Java in 32 bits machines

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was reading [Java concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) and got a bit lost in the paragraph below, concerning the number of threads that can be created in Java in 32 bits machines:

> On 32 bit machines, a major limiting factor is address space for
>   thread stacks. Each thread maintains two execution stacks, one for
>   Java code and one for native code. Typical JVM defaults yield a
>   combined stack size of around half a megabyte. (You can change this
>   with the -Xss JVM flag  or through  the  Thread  constructor.)  If 
>   you  divide  the  per thread  stack  size  into  2<sup>32</sup>,  you  get  a 
>   limit  of  a  few  thousands  or  tens  of  thousands  of  threads.
>   Other factors, such as OS limitations, may impose stricter limits.

What does this mean? Where does the 2<sup>32</sup> number come from? How I could change the stack size in the Thread constructor if there is not a constructor taking the stack size as parameter in the Thread class?

Comment: The 2^32 value is the size of the virtual address space available.

Comment: The 232 you were talking about was in reality 2^32. Do you still have a question now this typo has been fixed?

Comment: oh my god, in the pdf I have it was read as 232, thanks for fixing the typo ! :)

Comment: The grammar seems to be broken in that paragraph. I agree with the interpretation that it means, "if you divide the theoretically maximum address space by the minimum stack size then..." (however technically this is not correct when you think about segments). Nevertheless it is a bad idea to have that many threads anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The figure 2<sup>32</sup> is a hard limit on the size of the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) of a 32-bit process. “32-bit process” means that 32 bits are used to represent each address, and thus there can at most be 2<sup>32</sup> different addresses.

The paragraph is saying that since each thread must reserve about 512 * 1024 addresses just for the threads' stacks, there can be only so many threads since the number of addresses is limited.

Note that 2<sup>32</sup> is the theoretical, by-definition limit. In practice, you may consider yourself lucky if the OS makes 3/4 of that available to a 32-bit process.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String,%20long)) that takes stack size as a parameter.
2. `2^32` is the size of the virtual address space.